# How to change type of a field in mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, shell, database

I inserted some data in a database collection named Orders. And I have a field named `numberofh`.

But all fields in my collection are string types. I am connected to the mongo db shell on the server and I want to delete all orders where `numberofh` is less then 5.

`db.orders.remove({numberofh:{$lt:20}})` does not work because `numberofh` is a string so `$lt` won't work.

Can I do this some other way such as `sdb.orders.remove({parseInt(numberofh}:{$lt:20})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare strings with numbers in mongoDB. You have to first insert a new field, that is a numerical representation of `numberofh`. And you have to do the conversion client-side. There is no possibility, to create a field in dependency of the value of another field.

```
db.orders.find( {} ).forEach( function (x) {   
    x.numberofh_n = parseInt( x.numberofh, 10 ); 
    db.orders.save( x );
});
```

After that you can remove the records by the new field:

```
db.orders.remove( { numberofh_n: { $lt:20 } } )
```

Comment: This would be preferable to my solution if the change doesn't break some other functionality in the application. Something like this would not be feasible for my situation as other processes are expecting a certain format of documents...

Comment: You have a copy pasta error in your code... `sdb => db`

Comment: @heinob this worked just fine. But its changing only once, sec time i need to do it again, can i create that field to be there forever?

Comment: @user3332859: You cannot create the field for every new document automatically. Best would be, if you create it manually on every new document creation by yourself. If that is not possible --> yes, you have to do this over and over again :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to iterate over each of the documents and convert each value as the cursor reaches it:

```js
db.orders.find().forEach( function( doc ) {  
  // Extract the relevant value and convert to an int
  var numberofh_int = parseInt( doc[ "numberofh" ], 10 );
  // Perform conditionals on the value
  if ( numberofh_int < 20 ){ // $lt:20
    // Remove the document if it answers to the conditions
    db.orders.remove( doc );
  }
} );
```